# AJAX always goes to error when sending data to PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I have a problem with AJAX and PHP. AJAX should send data to PHP but it always returns error.
Even if i comment out gender radio button in js ajax and php the ajax still returns error. But in responsetext in console log it shows whole HTML code of unos.php. Please help.

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    Ime: <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Pera"></br>
    Prezime: <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Peric"></br>
    Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="pera@gmail.com"></br>
    Gender: </br>
    Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="male"></br>
    Female<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="female"></br>
    <input type="button" value="Insert" id="submit">
</form>
```

JS ABOVE AJAX:

```
var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var errors = document.getElementById("errors");
var gender = document.querySelector("input[type='radio']:checked");
var firstNameVal = $("#firstName").val();
var lastNameVal = $("#lastName").val();
var emailVal = $("#email").val();
var genderVal = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "unos.php",
  data: {
    firstNamePHP: firstNameVal,
    lastNamePHP: lastNameVal,
    emailPHP: emailVal,
    genderPHP: genderVal,
  },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  },
});
```

PHP unos.php:

```
<?php
    $firstName = $_POST["firstNamePHP"];
    $lastName = $_POST["lastNamePHP"];
    $email = $_POST["emailPHP"];
    define("ERROR_FIRSTNAME","Ime mora poceti velikim slovom i mora imati najmanje 3 slova");
    define("ERROR_LASTNAME","Prezime mora poceti velikim slovom i mora imati najmanje 3 slova");
    define("ERROR_EMAIL","Email se mora zavrsiti sa @gmail.com , @ict.edu.rs ili @yahoo.com");
    define("ERROR_GENDER","Morate izabrati pol");
    define("REGEX_NAME","/^[A-Z][a-z]{2,}$/");
    define("REGEX_EMAIL","/^.{1,15}@(gmail.com|ict.edu.rs|yahoo.com)$/");
    check($firstName,REGEX_NAME,ERROR_FIRSTNAME);
    check($lastName,REGEX_NAME,ERROR_LASTNAME);
    check($email,REGEX_EMAIL,ERROR_EMAIL);
    if(isset($_POST["genderPHP"]) AND !empty($_POST["genderPHP"])){
        $gender = $_POST["genderPHP"];
    }
    else {
        echo ERROR_GENDER;
    }
    function check($input,$regex,$error){
        if(preg_match($regex,$input) AND isset($input) AND !empty($input)){
            echo "Radi </br>";
        }
        else{
            echo $error;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: It sounds like your server isn't set up to run PHP.

Comment: XAMPP is turned on with Apache. I'm not using any kind of database.

Comment: So if you browse to `unos.php` what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

In your example you submit JSON but trying to get value from raw POST data. So, you need to to decode JSON

PHP unos.php:

```php
<?php


    // Decode AJAX Post JSON to $data array
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    $firstName = $data["firstNamePHP"]; // or use getArrayValue($data, "firstNamePHP", '');
    $lastName = $data["lastNamePHP"]; // or use getArrayValue($data, "lastNamePHP", '');
    $email = $data["emailPHP"]; // or use getArrayValue($data, "emailPHP", '');
    define("ERROR_FIRSTNAME","Ime mora poceti velikim slovom i mora imati najmanje 3 slova");
    define("ERROR_LASTNAME","Prezime mora poceti velikim slovom i mora imati najmanje 3 slova");
    define("ERROR_EMAIL","Email se mora zavrsiti sa @gmail.com , @ict.edu.rs ili @yahoo.com");
    define("ERROR_GENDER","Morate izabrati pol");
    define("REGEX_NAME","/^[A-Z][a-z]{2,}$/");
    define("REGEX_EMAIL","/^.{1,15}@(gmail.com|ict.edu.rs|yahoo.com)$/");
    check($firstName,REGEX_NAME,ERROR_FIRSTNAME);
    check($lastName,REGEX_NAME,ERROR_LASTNAME);
    check($email,REGEX_EMAIL,ERROR_EMAIL);
    if(isset($data["genderPHP"]) AND !empty($data["genderPHP"])){
        $gender = $data["genderPHP"];
    }
    else {
        echo ERROR_GENDER;
    }
    function check($input,$regex,$error){
        if(preg_match($regex,$input) AND isset($input) AND !empty($input)){
            echo "Radi </br>";
        }
        else{
            echo $error;
        }
    }
?>
```

To get array value I recommend you to use helper like this

```php
function getArrayValue($data, $key, $default = '') {
  if (isset($data[$key]) {
      return $data[$key];
  }

  return $default;
}
```